# Linq to SQL where both of the 2 columns must match from the list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

Previous Query

```
  var orderNameList = GetOrderNames().ToList();
  var orderTypes = orderTypeRepository.Query().Where(x => orderNameList.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

New Query (New Requirement - Get OrderTypes where both name and Region match from the list)

```
  var orderNameAndRegionList = document.OrderTypes
                                 .Select(x=> new { x.Name, x.RegionCode}).ToList(); //Anonymous Order list {Name, RegionCode}
  var orderTypes = orderTypeRepository.Query()
                             .Where(x => orderNameAndRegionList.Any(p => p.Name == x.Name && p.RegionCode == x.RegionCode))
                             .ToList()
```

This new query throws NHibernate exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: : ( : p1 )
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
```

I'm trying to **avoid** putting the query inside a foreach loop like this:

```
            orderNameAndRegionList.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var orderType = orderTypeRepository.Query().SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == x.Name && r.RegionCode == x.RegionCode);
                orderTypes.Add(orderType);
            });
```

Is there any better solution to avoiding query inside loop?

Comment: What's the type coming from GetOrderNamesWithRegion?

Comment: It is an Anonymous list with {Name, RegionCode} or List<string, string>

Comment: No, I mean without the .ToList(). Is it Queryable?

Comment: Can you show the code for it?

Comment: I think the problem is in the ToList(). At that moment the Query is sent to the DB (if the type from GerOrderNamesWithRegion is Queryable. In that case you could remove the ToList() from the call to the method and use your first solution.

Comment: LINQ always works in 2 stages. First the Query is created in memory. You can keep adding things to the Query until it (stage 2) is resolved using f.i. a .ToList(). At that moment the LINQ tree build in memory is translated to the SQL Query for the DB and executed and the result returned.

Comment: GetOrderNamesWithRegion is not IQueryable, it is simply a list like this     var documentOrderTypes = document.Properties?.OrderTypes?
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name))
                .Select(t => new {t.Name, RegionCode = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.RegionCode) ? localizationSettings.RegionCode : t.RegionCode})
                .ToList();

Comment: Again. Could you please edit your question and add the code for GetOrderNamesWithRegion?

Comment: @PaulSinnema, I think your last comment is helpful, I can create queries from list using a loop and build the tree and use ToList() after the loop finishes so that the query executes only once. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I have amended the question to expand on anonymous type

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or NHibernate? They are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding how LINQ works is key in your case. If the GetOrderNamesWithRegion returns a IQueryable<> type you can simply use it in your first solution. Below is a silly example that explains what happens when.

NHibernate does not support you using a List<anon<string,string>> inside a LINQ query but a IQueryable should be allowed.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace LINQExplanation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] db = new string[] { "value 1", "value 2", "value 3" };

            // Stage 1: My nonsense query but you get the picture
            var query = db
                .Where(v => v == "value 1")
                .Where(v => v == "value 2")
                .Where(v => v == "value 3");

            query.Where(v => v == "Non existent");

            // Until now nothing is read from the array;

            // Stage 2: the .ToList() resolves the query and the array is read.
            var result = query.ToList();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```